# gdb set breakpoint on a directory

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I am debugging a program which eventually calls the SDK to program the hardware. I don't know which API in the SDK the program calls when I trigger the problem. Is there a way to apply a blanket breakpoint over the SDK which halts the program when any function in the SDK/directory is called so that I know which API it calls and later backtrace it?

Or is there another better way?

Thanks!

Edit: The program and SDK are written in C.

Comment: Please provide some detailed information regarding the program(like which language has been used what is SDK). Without these information it would be difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Would the `rbreak` command help?  If your SDK functions all begin with `fpga_`, do `rbreak fpga_.*`. If your SDK functions are all in a file named `fpga_sdk.c`, do `rbreak fpga_sdk.c:.`